# Removing a view from .NET MVC project that is no longer needed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is a view in my MVC that is no longer needed and I would like to remove it properly beyond just taking away the button that allows users to navigate there.

There are the ActionResult functions in the associated Controller as well, and when I removed these functions as well as deleting the view.cshtml file, I encountered an error when I attempted to deploy the changes because the build was looking for the view.cshtml file that had been deleted.

I'm guessing there is a config file or something similar that has all of the various pages/references included and that is where the deployment is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be sure to delete the view from the project and not just the directory.  In VS just right-click on it and delete it.

Also be sure to save your project and that the updated .csproj gets sent to your build server.

Comment: Thank you. The .csproj file was not being included in the updates being sent.

Answer (score 1):

the file could possibly still be defined in the .csproj file if you didn't delete it within VS this would still be there and if you didn't deploy the change to the .csproj file also it would still be looking for the file in question